# Segmentation fault when using scanf for int?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, scanf, user-input

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int ops = 0;
    printf("Enter number of operations:");
    scanf("%d",&ops);

    FILE * fp = fopen (argv[0],"wb");
    //int i = 0;
    int key = 0;
    char op;
    for (int i = 0; i < ops; i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter a key:");
        //printf("\nhi");
        scanf("%d",&key);  // Line 20 -- Segfault
        printf("\nh");
        fwrite(&key,sizeof(int),1,fp);
        printf("\nNow enter an operation for that key:");
        scanf("%c",&op);
        fwrite(&op,sizeof(char),1,fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("Operations file written");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The program runs fine until the scanf on line 20, on the first loop itself. It returns "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". I am a little lost as to why this could be happening with a simple call to scanf.

Comment: While line numbers do make it easier to find the right line, they make it impossible to actually copy this and run it.

Comment: `argv[0]` is the exe name, isn't it?

Comment: What are the inputs you used to get the segfault?  It ran fine on my computer.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp makes a good point.  Are you sure you don't mean `argv[1]`?  The way you have it, you're overwriting your executable.

Comment: On many systems, attempting to open the executable for writing will simply fail - and the code doesn't check the return value of `fopen` to see if it succeeded.  If it failed, then `fp` is null and the `fwrite` call will likely segfault.  So I wonder if OP is just mistaken about the location of the crash.

Comment: I think your right. Probably.

Comment: Oh, nvm. When I go into `gdb`, it is in fact the call to `fwrite` that causes it. Simple print debugging was masking that.

Comment: The buffering may be the cause of the confusion - were you looking for the `h` to be output by printf?  It would have been buffered and not printed until the next `\n` was output, which only happens after the `fwrite`.

Comment: So, moral of the story: the `argv[0]` was an "honest bug" that anyone could have made.  But not checking for errors in `fopen`, or any other system call, is frankly just negligent.  And if you'd had a check there (with corresponding `perror` in case of failure), I suspect you'd have been able to find and fix the other bug by yourself.

Comment: You guys are right. I should be opening argv[1] instead of zero. Thank you. Also bad habit on my part for not checking. - @NateEldredge i could i have fixed it by myself.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting a segfault on the `fwrite` because `fp` is `NULL`

You are using `argv[0]` which is the name of the executable. And, you're *not* checking the result of `fopen` for success/failure.

Here's the corrected code. `#if 0` denotes old/your code. `#if 1` denotes added code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#if 1
#include <errno.h>
#endif

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int ops = 0;

    // do this first so you abort before prompting the user
#if 1
    // skip over program name
    --argc;
    ++argv;

    if (argc < 1) {
        fprintf(stderr,"No output filename specified\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    FILE *fp = fopen(*argv, "wb");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Unable to open '%s' -- %s\n",argv[0],strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }
#endif

    printf("Enter number of operations:");
    scanf("%d", &ops);

#if 0
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[0], "wb");
#endif

    // int i = 0;
    int key = 0;
    char op;

    for (int i = 0; i < ops; i++) {
        printf("\nEnter a key:");
        // printf("\nhi");
        scanf("%d", &key);
        printf("\nh");
        fwrite(&key, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
        printf("\nNow enter an operation for that key:");
        scanf("%c", &op);
        fwrite(&op, sizeof(char), 1, fp);

    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("Operations file written");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> When I run my program after, I enter my key, it prints out the enter an operation for that key, but as soon as that happens, the prompt for the next key shows up. What could be causing that?

You're *not* accounting for newlines ['\n'] and/or whitespace. These can be considered whitespace by `scanf`, so adding a space to the format can handle that:

```
scanf(" %d",&key);
```

Normally, the `%d` will skip whitespace when looking for a number, so `%d` is sufficient.

But, this still doesn't solve the real issue because it's the *second* `scanf` that is the problem. The [changed] `scanf` above will strip whitespace *before* the format.

But, it will *not* strip whitespace *after* the number.

So, the second `scanf("%c",&op);` [for a *single* char] will be *fulfilled* by the *newline* from the *previous* input line.

So, we need:

```
scanf(" %c",&op);
```

The above is a simple fix. Mostly, you'll have to consult the manpage for `scanf` and experiment with format specifiers to dump the newline.

A few more things ...

`fwrite` is [effectively]:

```
fwrite(buf,number_of_elements,size_of_single_element,stream)
```

So, your `fwrite` arguments are reversed from the idiomatic.

Also, when you're doing the `fwrite` for `key`, it is writing the *binary* value (i.e. 4 bytes) to the output file. That's okay, but, is that what you really want [vs. doing (e.g) `printf(fp,"%d");`?

Anyway, here's the updated code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#if 1
#include <errno.h>
#endif

#ifndef DEBUG
#define DEBUG       0
#endif

#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    do { \
        if (DEBUG) \
            printf("DEBUG: " _fmt); \
    } while (0)

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int ops = 0;

    // do this first so you abort before prompting the user
#if 1
    // skip over program name
    --argc;
    ++argv;

    if (argc < 1) {
        fprintf(stderr,"No output filename specified\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    FILE *fp = fopen(*argv, "wb");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Unable to open '%s' -- %s\n",argv[0],strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }
#endif

    printf("Enter number of operations:");
    scanf("%d", &ops);

#if 0
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[0], "wb");
#endif

    // int i = 0;
    int key = 0;
    char op;

    for (int i = 0; i < ops; i++) {
        printf("\nEnter a key:");
        // printf("\nhi");
#if 0
        scanf("%d", &key);
#else
        scanf(" %d", &key);
#endif
        dbgprt("key=%d\n",key);

        printf("\nh");
#if 0
        fwrite(&key, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
#else
        fwrite(&key, 1, sizeof(key), fp);
#endif

        printf("\nNow enter an operation for that key:");
        // NOTE/BUG: need to account for newline in scanf below
#if 0
        scanf("%c", &op);
#else
        scanf(" %c", &op);
#endif
        dbgprt("op='%c'\n",op);

#if 0
        fwrite(&op, sizeof(char), 1, fp);
#else
        fwrite(&op, 1, sizeof(op), fp);
#endif
    }

    fclose(fp);
    printf("Operations file written\n");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: But isn't `argv[0]` the executable name?

Comment: @sciencepiofficial No, because of the `--argc; ++argv;` above it

Comment: Silly me, didn't notice those two lines.

Comment: @CraigEstey thank you. It turns out that I was supposed to be using argv[1]. However, I have another question. When I run my program after, I enter my key, it prints out the enter an operation for that key, but as soon as that happens, the prompt for the next key shows up. What could be causing that?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using `argv[0]` which returns the executable name - you are essentially overwriting and thus corrupting your executable file. To get the file that you desire, use `argv[1]`.